# resizable gridview columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gridview

i have found this
[Resizable Gridview columns using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115783/resizable-gridview-columns-using-javascript)
and happy to implement this http://www.ita.es/jquery/jquery.grid.columnsizing.htm but it is working on any table(

```
<table >
        <tbody>
            <tr class="first">
                <td width="100">

                </td>
                <td width="200">

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
```

) but creating problem on gridview render html table(

```
   <table >
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th ></th><th></th>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td ></td><td>
                        </td><td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

)

Comment: Please state your question and add a proper title.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to have that plugin work only on certain tables instead of all tables, change this line:

```
$("table").columnSizing()
```

To this instead:

```
$(".columnresize").columnSizing()
```

Then to any table you want it applied to, add class `columnresize` like this:

```
<table class="columnresize">
...
</table>
```

Comment: i am telling about the table structure

Comment: @Surajit sorry no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: working nice on <tr class="first">
                <td width="100">

                </td>
                <td width="200">

                </td>
              
            </tr> but not in gridview generated table because of 'th'
<tr>
                    <th ></th><th></th>
                </tr>

Comment: @Surjit are talking about asp.net generated Grid-view.. if it is so.. there is still no problem assign the CssClass property the name of the Class.. .net will emit the css class as is... and it will work as mentioned in above answer..

Comment: the drag area is not selecting properly.it is working.say i want to drag col2 so selection should start with  col2 but in my case drag area is starting from col1 and its dragged accordingly.pls try with a asp.net gridview control